# How to get the header to auto adjust its height to its content?

Tags: html, css

Using flexbox, I styled the links with padding and bottom border line but the border line shows out past the header line, how to get the links and their bottom border line to completely be within the header?

Isn't the container supposed to auto adjust to fit its content?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

body>header,
body>footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  /* padding: 0.25rem; */
}

body>header .link {
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body>header .link:hover,
body>header .link:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

body>header .link.title {
  font-size: larger;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

body>main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="link title">One</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Two</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Three</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Four</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Five</a>
  </header>
  <main></main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a while banging my head I finally found the way... I just had to set the header's `display: flex;` and just like that it works, no need to specify the header's dimensions nor margin nor padding, I'm a happy camper!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

body>header,
body>footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

body>header .link {
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body>header .link:hover,
body>header .link:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

body>main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="link">One</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Two</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Three</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Four</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Five</a>
  </header>
  <main></main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have have defined padding for `body > header .link` , the border goes off.

You can add padding or define height to `<header>`, problem will be fixed.

For example: (Adding `padding:0.5rem` to `<header>` tag)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1rem;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }

      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
      }
      
      body > header {
        padding:0.5rem
      }

      body > header,
      body > footer {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        background-color: white;
        border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
        /* padding: 0.25rem; */
      }

      body > header .link {
        color: blue;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
        outline: 0;
        padding: 0.25rem;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      body > header .link:hover,
      body > header .link:focus {
        border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
      }

      body > header .link.title {
        font-size: larger;
        font-variant: small-caps;
      }

      body > main {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="#" class="link">One</a>
      <a href="#" class="link">Two</a>
      <a href="#" class="link">Three</a>
      <a href="#" class="link">Four</a>
      <a href="#" class="link">Five</a>
    </header>
    <main></main>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried that, it does work, but I want the header to auto adjust its height to its content.

Comment: you should use ```margin``` instead of ```padding```. You don't either need to add padding/margin to ```<header>``` then

Comment: If I use margin on the header then the header separates from the edges of the document and I don't want that.

Comment: If I use margin on the links then the bottom border doesn't go past the sides of the links.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a padding bottom to the header. I just tried this in the sandbox and it seems to be working for me.

```css
header{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I tried padding too, but I want the header to auto adjust to the height of its content.

Answer (score 0):

You should try putting `padding-left: 0.25rem` instead of `padding: 0.25rem` under the selector `body>header .link`. Like below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

body>header,
body>footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

body>header .link {
  color: blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0 0.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  border
}

body>header .link:hover,
body>header .link:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

body>header .link.title {
  font-size: larger;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

body>main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

header {
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="link title">One</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Two</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Three</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Four</a>
    <a href="#" class="link">Five</a>
  </header>
  <main></main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Hope it resolves your problem.

Comment: You have the right idea since what I want is that the bottom border sits right on top of the header line but when you do that the bottom border extends beyond the text only on the left and there's no space between the text and the bottom border, I want to create space all around the link and by using padding I also have the bottom border extend before and after the text.

Comment: @JorgeZ can you explain little better, because I couldn't properly get what you are saying. I think I got what you were saying but just for reassurance can you explain it?

Comment: What I want is something like the menu on https://pub.dev/packages/pdf look at the menu "Readme | Changelog | Example | Installing | Versions | Scores"

Comment: I have edited my answer, does it suffice your need. Lemme know if it doesn't answer your problem.

Comment: That's the idea, except the height should be 30px so the link's bottom border sits on top of the header bottom line which I also could do by setting the header line as "flex: 0 0 30px", It's just that I thought the header should auto adjust to its content's size without having to specify the height.

Comment: @JorgeZ But I can't find any difference between my answer and the website of which the link you shared. They both seem the same to me.

Comment: When a div is created and put content inside there's no need to specify it's dimensions, it auto adjusts its size to fit its content, why doesn't the header auto adjust its size to fit my content?

Comment: It does auto adjust for the "content" for eg. try adding ```<br>``` and it will auto adjust. But it is not auto adjusting in your case because you have added a ```border-bottom```. So according to me you would've to hardcode it. According to me you should not use ```border-bottom``` or just hardcode the border.

Comment: I just want to say that your header is not auto-adjusting for the ```border-bottom```.

Comment: After spending a while banging my head I finally found the way... It was just matter of setting the header's display as flex `display: flex;` I already posted the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fit your parent element to it's child , so Just try `display:auto`

Comment: Can't do that because I'm using flexbox as the display.